# Postfix multiple checks

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp

I want to achieve the following with Postfix:

1. Run all emails through a black list
2. Allow any clients sending to a list of domains
3. Allow some clients sending to any domain

This is what I have: (postfix is on 10.0.8.0 and some of the senders are 10.0.8.0 and 10.0.9.0)

```
mynetworks_style = subnet

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access sqlite:/etc/postfix/access-bl.query, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/trusted_clients, check_recipie
nt_access hash:/etc/postfix/local_domains, reject_unauth_destination, permit
```

So, right now the black list works. File `/etc/postfix/trusted_clients` contains who can send anywhere (3), file `/etc/postfix/local_domains` contains where you can send (2).
Those two are fine, they return properly.

My problem is getting all three working together. Not sure if it's an ordering issue.
Currently sending a test from 10.0.9.17 and I get `Relay access denied`. If I add:

```
mynetworks = 10.0.8.0/24 10.0.9.0/24
```

then anyone can send anywhere, so #2 is not working.

Postfix version is 2.10 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any ideas?

Output of `postconf | grep restrictions`:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_data_restrictions =
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = 
smtpd_etrn_restrictions = 
smtpd_helo_restrictions = 
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access sqlite:/etc/postfix/access-bl.query, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/trusted_clients, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/local_domains, reject_unauth_destination, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination 
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
```

Comment: What is output of command `postconf | grep restrictions` ?

Comment: smtpd_client_restrictions = **** <br/> ****
smtpd_data_restrictions =  **** <br/> ****
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = *<br/>*
smtpd_etrn_restrictions = *<br/>*
smtpd_helo_restrictions = *<br/>*
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access sqlite:/etc/postfix/access-bl.query, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/trusted_clients, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/local_domains, reject_unauth_destination, permit_mynetworks *<br/>*
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination *<br/>*
smtpd_sender_restrictions = *<br/>*

Comment: Do you permit client `10.0.9.17` to sending with file `/etc/postfix/trusted_clients`? (e.g. Did you put line like `10.0.9.17    OK` in that file?)

Comment: No, because I don't want 10.0.9.17 to be able to send everywhere, just to local_domains...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In postfix 2.10, new parameter `smtpd_relay_restrictions` was introduced. This restriction will evaluated **BEFORE** `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

Snippet from [official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions)

> smtpd_relay_restrictions (default: permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination)
>   Access restrictions for mail relay control that the Postfix SMTP server applies in the context of the RCPT TO command, before smtpd_recipient_restrictions. See SMTPD_ACCESS_README, section "Delayed evaluation of SMTP access restriction lists" for a discussion of evaluation context and time.

Therefore, any client outside `mynetworks` will get `Relay Access Denied` because this rule `defer_unauth_destination`.

One of the solution is move your restriction (2) and (3) in `smtpd_relay_restrictions`.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    check_recipient_access sqlite:/etc/postfix/access-bl.query

smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks, 
    permit_sasl_authenticated, 
    check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/trusted_clients, 
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/local_domains,
    reject_unauth_destination
```

**Note:**

1. You can place [reject_unauth_destination](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination) in either `smtpd_relay_restrictions` or `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. No need to repeat it both place.
2. `smtpd_relay_restrictions` is intended to place where you putrelay rule, while `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is placeholder for spam blacklisting (for example [reject_non_fqdn_sender](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_non_fqdn_sender)).